# Check Swift array elements for multiple conditions

Tags: swift

I have Array of objects, that contain property with string value. What i want is, to return a Bool value that indicate, wether array contain not less then 2 objects:
 - One object have string property that value is equal to "foo"
 - One object have string property that value is equal to "bar"

So far i solve this only with "ugly" approach:

```
!myArr.filter{ $0.property  == "foo"}.isEmpty &&
          !myArr.filter{ $0.property  == "bar"}.isEmpty
```

Is there better approach?

Here is simple code in Playground that work with that approach:

```
struct Obj {
  var foo: String
}

let arr = [Obj(foo: "foo"), Obj(foo: "bar"), Obj(foo: "zoo")]

let result = !arr.filter{ $0.foo  == "foo"}.isEmpty && !arr.filter{ $0.foo  == "bar"}.isEmpty
print(result)
```

Comment: `myArr.contains(where: { $0.property == "foo" }) && myArr.contains(where: { $0.property == "bar" })`? This iteration should stop at first found and not continue whereas filter will continue to iterate the whole array (even if "found at first").

Comment: @Larme there is 2 iterations, so it actually (Bool & Bool), which is also Bool

Comment: I meant comparing `filter` & `contains`. It's better to use `contains` if you are doing a `isEmpty` test afterwards.

Comment: @Larme oh, thanks, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
(["foo", "bar"] as Set).isSubset( of: myArr.map(\.property) )
(["foo", "bar"] as Set).isSubset( of: arr.map(\.foo) )
```

Comment: well i guess it should work but it look intimidating for me :)

Comment: Maybe i did wrong, but it's not compiles (["foo", "bar"] as Set).isSubset( of: arr.map(\.foo ))

Full code in playground is: 
struct Obj {
  var foo: String
}

let arr = [Obj(foo: "foo"), Obj(foo: "bar"), Obj(foo: "zoo")]

(["foo", "bar"] as Set).isSubset( of: arr.map(\.foo ))

Comment: Compiles fine here. Make sure you're using Xcode 11.4.

Comment: It depends on Swift versions. The "safe" way is to do `myArr.map{ $0.property }`, it's more compatible with various versions of Swift.

Comment: @Jessy i guess it only works when 'property' is hashable and comforms to 'equatable'?

Comment: Yes. If you need something that doesn't fit that criteria, update the question, and I'll offer an alternative. It won't be as simple. Also, while you can do it without `Hashable`,  you can't without `Equatable`.

Answer (score -1):

@Larme is right, if You consider time complexity, worst/best case of `filter` is **O(n)**, while using `contains` or `first` can be less than **O(n)** or even **O(1)**

so the best choice for this condition is:

```
myArr.contains(where: {$0.propery == "foo"}) && myArr.contains(where: {$0.propery == "bar"})
```

or

```
((myArr.first(where: {$0.propery == "foo"}) != nil) && (myArr.first(where: {$0.propery == "bar"}) != nil)
```

Comment: I belive contains is still O(n)